# error in implementing the adaptive chained delayed payment in paypal

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments

second receiver does not get the payments after executing the execute_payments.php.Although it shows only the payment of primary user in the sandbox test account

Comment: Do you need more clarification on that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What value are you setting in ActionType? If you set PAY_PRIMARY then payment will reach primary only

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that these 2 Fiedls are set as suggested

In PayRequest -> actionType = PAY_PRIMARY and also ensure that feesPayer is not set as "SENDER" as this is not a valid value for chained payment.

If this doesn't work paste the request here for us to look and suggest.